# Error opening MINC 2.0 images with SimpleITK 0.5.1 C# Windows

Tags: c#, itk, minc

I am trying to load an MINC 2.0 Image with SimpleITK 0.5.1 C# version

I get the following error:

```
System.ApplicationException : Exception thrown in SimpleITK ImageFileReader_Execute: ..\..\..\..\..\ITK\Modules\IO\HDF5\src\itkHDF5ImageIO.cxx:883:
itk::ERROR: HDF5ImageIO(000000001DBE7AE0): H5Dopen2 failed
```

My code is as follows:

```
String fileName = @"d:\Temp\MRI\tst-convert.mnc";

ImageFileReader reader = new ImageFileReader();
reader.SetFileName(fileName);
Image image = reader.Execute();
```

Do you have an suggestions what can cause such error?
Should I install some additional libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from ITK User group: Current version of SimpleITK and also ITK can not read MINC Images.

Answer (score 1):

As of ITK version 4.4 a new MINC IO module has been contributed. This is not enabled by default, and is not include with the SimpleITK version. However a custom ITK can be build with this module enabled, by enabling the "Module_ITKIOMINC" cmake option. Then a custom SimpleITK can be built against that version of ITK.